# Spring: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. How can I know(get) a list of all properties for this bean?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I searched via internet and I saw so much different examples: **Spring + JPA (Hibernate)**.
And each example contains **entityManagerFactory** bean in **Spring** application context file.
Everytime, this bean contains a list of properties. And my question below:

How can I determine full list of properties available for this bean?

Comment: do you mean properties you set on the bean, or the values for the jpaProperties field?

Comment: @incomplete-co.de, both

Answer (score 0):

If you mean properties of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, then it's like all other Spring beans: locate the public setter methods of the class and its super-classes. A quick look at the class itself shows these properties (without considering the super-class):

`dataSource, jtaDataSource, loadTimeWeaver, mappingResources, packagesToScan, persistenceUnitManager, persistenceUnitName, persistenceUnitPostProcessors, persistenceXmlLocation, resourceLoader`

As for jpaProperties, it depends on the JPA implementation you're working with. For Hibernate, you can have a look at this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html